# graphics window invoked from r command prompt but not with rscript.exe

Tags: r, plot

I have an R script (which opens a displays a map and some data) which I am able to invoke from the R command prompt using `source("myFile.R")`. However when I try to invoke with `rscipt.exe`, nothing happens. How do I get the graphics window to come up?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does plot, but the script exits immediately and you will never notice. You could try this -

```
x11()
plot(1:10)
locator(1)
```

Or some system sleep should also work.

Comment: however when running Rscript, it is recommended that you print to `pdf` or `png`